# WPF ribbon control: RibbonContextualTabGroup hiding title

Tags: .net, wpf, ribbon

I'm creating an application that uses Microsoft's Ribbon but I'm having issues with the RibbonContextualTabGroup.  When this tab appears it changes the title text specified in the ribbon properties to "E.....", is there a way round this?

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<r:RibbonWindow x:Class="Sample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:r="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
    Title="Example Ribbon" Height="600" Width="800" FontFamily="Arial" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
            Background="White">

<r:Ribbon DockPanel.Dock="Top" Title="Example" >
    <r:Ribbon.ContextualTabGroups>
        <r:RibbonContextualTabGroup Color="Yellow" Width="120" Name="ribbonCtxGroup" Label="Dataset">
            <r:RibbonTab Name="ribbonTabDataset" Label="Dataset">
                <r:RibbonTab.Groups>

                    <r:RibbonGroup >
                        <r:RibbonGroup.Command>
                            <r:RibbonCommand LabelTitle="Pages" />
                        </r:RibbonGroup.Command>
                    </r:RibbonGroup>

                </r:RibbonTab.Groups>
            </r:RibbonTab>
        </r:RibbonContextualTabGroup>
    </r:Ribbon.ContextualTabGroups>
</r:Ribbon>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't tried this (or don't need it) try deleting the Title="Example" from r:Ribbon or Title="Example Ribbon" from r:RibbonWindow.